# Formatting HTML lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have this:

```
<ol type="1">
   <li>
      List Item 1
      <ol>
         <li>
            Nested Item 1.1
         </li>
         <li>
            Nested Item 1.2
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li>
      List Item 2
   </li>
</ol>
```

and I want it to be printed like this:

[image: listing like MS word or OpenOffice]

Comment: For Your HTML you will not get your expected result.You Have specified the `List Item` values as `Nested Item 1.1` and `Nested Item 1.2` but expecting as `1.1 Nested Item ` and `1.2 Nested Item `

Comment: @chiLLer Yes, it's possible, using counters. See my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS Outline numbering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956178/html-css-outline-numbering)

Comment: @FakeHeal did you really mean the numbering of the output to be determined by the text in the inner `<li>`s instead of the physical order they appear in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your exact HTML, you want this:

```
ol[type="1"] {counter-reset:outer 0}
ol[type="1"] > li {counter-increment:outer}
ol[type="1"] ol {counter-reset:inner 0}
ol[type="1"] ol > li {list-style:none; counter-increment:inner}
ol[type="1"] ol > li::before {content:counter(outer) "." counter(inner)}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyjhW/) for a working example.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this isn't supported by IE7 or older.

Comment: would be able to fix this by simply removing the non IE compat selectors. eg, using ol li instead of ol > li

Comment: @Lister i do upvote your answer, but check his expected output. The Nested items you were printing like `1.1 Nested Item 1.1` but what he want is `1.1 Nested Item 1` and this is not possible unless use of script by changing element values, or he could mistaken typing

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant. Yes, the OP's output is different from the text in the list items. I missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

style:

```
#ext-ol ol{
    padding-left:40px;
}​
```

html:

```
<ol type="1" id="ext-ol">
   <li>
      List Item 1
      <ol id="int-ol">
         <li>
            Nested Item 1.1
         </li>
         <li>
            Nested Item 1.2
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li>
      List Item 2
   </li>
</ol>​
```