# order list in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have to make terms and conditions page in html so i want to give them a number but some conditions have their sub point so i want to show them like below example.

1. me the first point

   1.1 and me the sub point
2. me the second point
3. me the third point
4. me the forth

   4.1 and me the sub point

it is possible to give them such a number format using css

```
<style>
ol {list-style:decimal}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<ol>

<li>me the first point
<ol><li>me the sub point</li></ol>

</li>
<li>me the second point</li>
<li>me the third point</li>
<li>me the forth point</li>


</ol>

</body>
```

Comment: You can find an answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956178/html-css-outline-numbering or here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852816/nested-ordered-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS **counter-increment** for this. write like this:

```
 body{
   counter-reset: chapter 0;
 }
 li{
   counter-reset: sub-chapter 0;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:relative;
 }
 li:before{
   counter-increment: chapter;
   content: counter(chapter) ". ";
 }
 li li:before{
   counter-increment: sub-chapter;
   content: counter(chapter) "." counter(sub-chapter) ": ";
 }
li:before{
    position:absolute;
    left:-20px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gNqXL/

It's work till IE8 & above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with css counters.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/automatic-numbering-with-css-counters/

Answer (score 1):

I think this suits your requirement:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-reset.asp

Answer (score 0):

Terms and Conditions is generally a static page. So it is better to use manual order instead of generating dynamically

Answer (score 0):

CSS can do this.

http://caniuse.com/#search=counter

[See example](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/501/nested-counters-example.html).

This may point you in a decent direction.