# Ordered list CSS style includes parent number

Tags: css, html-lists, nested

We're looking to use CSS to create an ordered list that looks like this:

```
A.
A.1
A.2
B.
C.
C.1
C.2
C.2.1
C.2.2
```

How would you include the parent index in the child like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS Outline numbering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956178/html-css-outline-numbering)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [CSS counters <sup>W3C specs</sup>](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-lists/#counter-set) (*as [@Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841818/128165)*) has pointed out, but here is an approach that will handle multiple nesting and latin counters ..

```
ol{
    list-style: none;
}
ol.roman{
    counter-reset: roman;
}
ol.roman > li:before{
    counter-increment: roman;
    content: counter(roman, upper-latin)".";
    padding-right:5px;
}
ol.roman li ol{
    counter-reset: inner;
}
ol.roman ol li:before{
    counter-increment: inner;
    content: counter(roman, upper-latin)"."counters(inner,'.');
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nZQSF/

Comment: Spot on - was busy implementing the other answer when I realised it wasn't using alpha characters as I specified in the question

Comment: Nice solution, but in real world you will always have multiline items, and it will not look perfect (counters will become almost invisible).

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/counters).

#### Example ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/counters))

CSS:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;                /* Creates a new instance of the
                                            section counter with each ol
                                            element */
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: section;            /* Increments only this instance
                                            of the section counter */
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";   /* Adds the value of all instances
                                            of the section counter separated
                                            by a ".". */
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol>
 <li>Entry
 <li>Entry
 <li>Entry with subentries
  <ol>
    <li>Entry
    <li>Entry
    <li>Entry
    <li>Entry
  </ol>
 <li>Entry
 <li>Entry
 <li>Entry with subentries
  <ol>
    <li>Entry
    <li>Entry
    <li>Entry
    <li>Entry
  </ol>
</ol>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8MWdL/1/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Don't worry, I know this. However, I wasn't able to edit my answer since I wasn't able to open stackoverflow.com for about 20 minutes. I guess there's something wrong with my VPN.

Comment: Just so you know, that's a canned comment from the Low Quality review page--your answer got picked up for having a link and very little other content. It should be fine now--thanks for improving it!

Comment: Thanks. I added the closing </li> tags in jsfiddle and it broke, which is a problem because we're getting the markup back from a wysiwyg control.  Is there a simple fix?

Comment: My bad, I was putting some of the tags in the wrong places.  Working fine now.